# OAuth package for Django-nonrel

Tags: django, oauth, oauth-2.0, django-authentication, django-nonrel

Can anyone help me to find an OAuth package (1.0 or 2.0) that can work with Django-nonrel?

oauth2app is very good, but it uses: scope = models.ManyToManyField(AccessRange)
so that it cannot be used with Django-nonrel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using django-social-auth with django-nonrel.

https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth#oauth

BUT I've only used the FB backend.  It seems to work fine, without use of ManyToMany.  There's an OAuth backend as well, but I haven't tried it, and I'm not certain whether it uses ManyToMany.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try django-social-auth. I still hope to know the options. If anyone knows this issue, please tell me.

Comment: djano-social-auth is not an OAuth package. It needs an OAuth package to run. The problem is still unsolved.

Comment: Sorry about that, I haven't gotten deep enough with it.

Comment: No need to say sorry. I learned about social-auth and that is helpful. Still trying to find one. Thanks.